# Win 7 hangs at welcome screen - no errors in event viewer

Tags: windows-7

I can't seem to figure this out and it is bothering me.

My computer freezes on the welcome screen. I can switch to different users to enter credentials in, open help items and change logon domains; but when I hit Enter to login the computer freezes.

I tried to look for an error in the Event Viewer, but nothing showed up except a Critical Error when I had to do a hard shutdown. I can go into Safe Mode (and w/networking) and everything works fine.

I haven't installed anything or done any updates in several weeks, I only use Chrome to web surf and don't download anything from the internet.

System File Checker:nothing
Check Disk:nothing
Virus Scan:nothing
Disable startup items and non-windows services(Clean Boot):nothing
Last known good configuration:nothing

(P.S. I looked at the other Similar Questions and nothing seemed to fit my problem. If one does, please show me.)

Comment: have you restored to a point before the last update or the last time you installed anything?

Comment: I restored to before the last update and nothing changed.

Comment: Did you try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Comment: @and31415 Clean boot did not work

Comment: Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F3` at the welcome screen.  Can you get into audit mode?

Comment: @Colyn1337 can't get there. As soon as I press `enter` to login, it freezes

Comment: @bobSmith1432 don't try to login.  When you get to the login screen, press the keys I gave you.

Comment: @Colyn1337 nothing happens

Comment: @bobSmith1432 Try [using Last Known Good Configuration](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-last-known-good-configuration#1TC=windows-7).

Comment: @Colyn1337 didn't work

Answer (score 0):

How long have you waited for it to login? If a profile is corrupted and it has to fully downlaod the profile from the domain server, it can take up to 30 minutes on big profiles, depending on what people store in their userprofiles. More often than not, I found people storing up to 2 gb of word and excel documents, etc in their my documents folder which is stored in their userprofile. It can take a really long time to log in. Note that at all times during the login, the circle is rotating. If that stops, then you know it crashed.

Comment: As soon as I hit login (enter), the circle stops spinning.

Comment: I see. That indeed should not happen. I can't think of anything off the head what it could be. In these cases I would not look too much and instead just reinstall windows.